# Colorbox has broken my site. Help!

Tags: javascript

I had downloaded the libraries module. I then watched another tutorial which told me to CREATE  a libraries directory in the sites/all folder. WHich I did, I then downloaded the colorbox plug in and pasted it in the empty libraries directory. I am now getting the following error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function libraries_get_path() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/devel/devel.module on line 407

I deleted both libraries directories to start from scratch but the error is still there. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[libraries_get_path](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!libraries!libraries.module/function/libraries_get_path/7) is defined in `libraries.module`

Make sure the [Libraries API](http://drupal.org/project/libraries) module ( e.g 7.x-2.0 ) is installed and enabled.

Comment: I can't get to admin/modules :(

Comment: I copied the libraries directory over again and it's all good again. Phew!

Comment: Yes, in future, uninstall the module via the drupal admin user interface _first_ ( disable, save then uninstall, save ) then you can delete the folder. Glad it's fixed.

Comment: The Libraries module was surely installed, or [devel_init()](http://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/devel_init/7) (the function causing the error) would not have tried to use `libraries_get_path()`. The function first checks the module is enabled (`elseif (module_exists('libraries')) {`).

Comment: Yes, was a broken install where OP deleted the module folder, a proper install of libraries API fixed it.